# How to disable safe volume warning SystemUI

Tags: java

Hello i deodexed systemui and from com/android/systemui/volume/VolumeDialogControllerImpl.smali i edited this code with another i found on web but not working have black screen with no status bar. what do i need to edit now to complete disable safe volume warning on earphones.

.method private onShowSafetyWarningW(I)V
    .locals 2
    .param p1, "flags"    # I

```
.prologue
.line 371
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/android/systemui/volume/VolumeDialogControllerImpl;->mKnoxStateMonitor:Lcom/android/systemui/KnoxStateMonitor;

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/android/systemui/KnoxStateMonitor;->isSafetyWarningDialogEnabled()Z

move-result v0

xor-int/lit8 v0, v0, 0x1

.line 370
if-eqz v0, :cond_0

.line 372
sget-object v0, Lcom/android/systemui/volume/VolumeDialogControllerImpl;->TAG:Ljava/lang/String;

const-string/jumbo v1, "KnoxStateMonitor : Disable SafetyWarningDialog"

invoke-static {v0, v1}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

.line 373
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/android/systemui/volume/VolumeDialogControllerImpl;->mAudio:Landroid/media/AudioManager;

invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/media/AudioManager;->disableSafeMediaVolume()V

.line 374
return-void

.line 376
:cond_0
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/android/systemui/volume/VolumeDialogControllerImpl;->mCallbacks:Lcom/android/systemui/volume/VolumeDialogControllerImpl$C;

invoke-virtual {v0, p1}, Lcom/android/systemui/volume/VolumeDialogControllerImpl$C;->onShowSafetyWarning(I)V

.line 377
return-void
```

.end method